# app.js:10567 [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-9

No clue where the error coming from, hours trying to find it.
All the components the same.
Configure vue router is a nightmare.

Error:

> app.js:10567 [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render
> function.    at <CreateProduct onVnodeUnmounted=fn
> ref=Ref< undefined > >    at     at     at

**http://localhost**

[image]

**http://localhost/create**

[image]

router.js

```
import AllProduct from './components/AllProduct.vue';
import CreateProduct from './components/CreateProduct.vue';
import EditProduct from './components/EditProduct.vue';

import {createWebHistory, createRouter} from "vue-router";
 
const routes = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        path: '/',
        component: AllProduct
    },
    {
        name: 'create',
        path: '/create',
        component: CreateProduct
    },
    {
        name: 'edit',
        path: '/edit/:id',
        component: EditProduct
    }
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: routes,
});

export default router;
```

app.js

```
 require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp,h } from 'vue';
import router from './routes';
import App from './App.vue';
import axios from 'axios'

const app = createApp({ render: () => h(App) });
app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container"> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <router-link to="/" class="nav-item nav-link">Products List</router-link>
                    <router-link to="/create" class="nav-item nav-link">Create Product</router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <router-view> </router-view>
    </div>
</template>
 
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

AllProducts.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2 class="text-center">Products List</h2>
 
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Detail</th>
                <!-- <th>Actions</th> -->
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
                <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.detail }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <router-link :to="{name: 'edit', params: { id: product.id }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</router-link>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteProduct(product.id)">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
 
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                products: [] 
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.axios
                .get('/api/products/')
                .then(response => {
                    this.products = response.data;
                });
        },
        methods: {
            deleteProduct(id) { 
                this.axios
                    .delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/products/${id}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        let i = this.products.map(data => data.id).indexOf(id);
                        this.products.splice(i, 1)
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try `const app = createApp(App);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you read the red error, it says `cannot read propertie of undefined (reading 'get')`

That means your trying to access the `get` propertie of an `undefined` object

looking for `get`in your code, we find :

```
this.axios
    .get('/api/products/')
```

so that means `this.axios` is `undefined`

it's undefined cause you declared it like this :

```
app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;
```

with a `$` sign